# Need to change background-position onMouseOver

Tags: javascript, html, inline

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('button1Inline').style.backgroundPosition='0px -90px';">
    <img src="ads/button1.png" id="button1Inline" />
</a>
```

The button1.png is a 180 pixels tall sprite comprised of two effect halves.  Due to unnatural forces beyond my control I have to make this work inline.  I know it's not best practice and I feel terrible about myself, but right now I just need it to work.  Please and thanks!

Comment: Ooooh, Are you trying to change the background position of an image tag? How's that working out for you?

Comment: I don't know, normally I'd do this with a hover effect from the css with an anchor or container tag.  So I should be using a background image on the anchor and setting the text-indent to -9999px?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do that could be having a HTML like this:

```
<a href="#" id="button1"></a>
```

And you could give it CSS properties like `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` with the width of your image and half the height of it and then a `:hover` style.

For example:

```
#button1 {
    display: block;
    width: 180px; /* assuming it's square */
    height: 90px;
    background: url(<path_to_images>/button1.png) top left no-repeat transparent;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
#button1:hover {
    background-position: 0 -90px;
}
```

That way you don't need any Javascript and have no side-effects.

Remember `background-position` just works for HTML elements that have a `background-image` set.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, and I do this with CSS all the time so I realize what a stupid question this seems like on the surface.  Unfortunately I need this to work inline, and the <style> tag isn't working inside of this container.  Or maybe it can and I just don't know how.

Comment: If it's imperative that you work inline you may do `<a href="#" style="<enter previous style here>" onMouseOver="<your code here>"></a>`. If you have a `img` tag then I bet you can't change its `background-position` because the image isn't the background.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought about the src attribute of an img tag not being the same as the background style attribute of a conatiner tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('button1Inline').style.backgroundPosition='-55px 0px';" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('button1Inline').style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px';">
    <div id="button1Inline" style="background-image:url(110crunchglovesi.png);width:55px;height:110px;background-position:0px 0px"
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the right track.  I hadn't thought about the src attribute of an img tag not being the same as the background style attribute of a conatiner tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should place an empty 1px x 1px gif in the src of the img tag. The "ads/button1.png" image should be place in the img CSS as background-image.

Comment: Hmm... I disagree. Spacers are so 1990.  This can easily be done without hacky stuff.

Comment: You should look for a definition of the term "hack."

Comment: I'm just pointing out the fact that spacers aren't (see also: shouldn't be) used anymore, and with good reason.

Comment: I'm just pointing out the fact that I'm not finding anything "hacky" about spacers.

Comment: @NominalAeon as always, there are no stupid questions, just stupid answers.